# Brightness on monitor

Tags: desktop, brightness

My Dell all-in-one seems to have a mind of it's own. The brightness pop-up comes on the screen and sets to zero, without me touching it. I have ran the diagnostic and it says my monitor is fine. But the brightness continues to re-set itself. How can I fix this?

Comment: Please provide model.

Comment: I wonder if its some wierd adaptive brightness thing. And yes, we'd at least need to know what model it is, and whether this has always been happening or its something new. Help us help you

Comment: It is a Dell F185A monitor, but it is an all-in-one. I also found this info: Pentium dual core CPU E5500 @ 2.80 GHz 2.79GHz
--This problem just began out of the blue. I ran a full virus scan and it said everything was clean.